# PHP How to extract first days of the weeks from a Month from Unix timestamp

Tags: php, unix

There is this Unix timestamp and it needs to generate the first days of the week as an array.

```
    $time = '1456034400'; 
    // This present Month February 2016
    // in calendar the February has the start of the week 
    // Sunday 7
    // Sunday 14
    // Sunday 21
    // Sunday 28
```

How do you get an array like this from the Unix Timestamp:

```
    $weekdays = array(
                  0 => 7,
                  1 => 14,
                  2 => 21,
                  3 => 28
                 );
```

And this method needs to work and be accurate for any given month in years not  just Feb 2016.

Comment: Sorry made an mistake with the code. Check it now, added the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getSundays($y, $m)
{
    return new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime("first Sunday of $y-$m"),
        DateInterval::createFromDateString('next sunday'),
        new DateTime("last day of $y-$m")
    );
}


$days="";
foreach (getSundays(2016, 04) as $Sunday) {
    $days[] = $Sunday->format("d");
}

var_dump($days);
```

https://3v4l.org/DVYM5

Answer (score 2):

A bit faster way (since it uses a simple calculation to iterate weeks):

```
$time = 1456034400;

$firstDay = strtotime('first Sunday of '.date('M',$time).' '.date('Y',$time));
$lastDay =  mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$time)+1,1,date('Y', $time));

$weekdays = array();

for ($i = $firstDay; $i < $lastDay; $i += 7*24*3600){
    $weekdays[] = date('d',$i);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/lQkB2/perf#tabs

Comment: It's actually equally fast. In my code I used april, I don't know why, I tested another month and it worked and I forgot to change back to february. But with february the time is also 0.017 as yours. https://3v4l.org/WHY8Z/perf#tabs

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't looks like the preformance measurement tool on 3v4l is trustful, since it may show a very different results even for the same script (try to add spaces to re-run scripts). I just assumed that simple operations with numbers works faster than parsing a string for several times ('next sunday', 'last day'). So the less string parsing is used the faster it works. Of course this will be really noticable only for a billions of iterations. So "a bit" is the keyword :) Regards.

Comment: Sorry but I find this funny. You don't believe the numbers are correct because you believe your operations with only numbers are easier. If you don't believe the numbers then do a real test  locally. If you find it important.